# JavaScript Form Validation Not working properly

Tags: javascript, forms

This is my HTML/Javascript Code.I am submitting the filled form to a Servlet. There seems to some problem with the form validation. I am not able to figure out why. It is supposed to prompt me to enter a new value if I enter 0 in textbox2 and select Divide from the drop down list box. But it doesn't and the form is submitted without any prompting to the servlet which throws Exception due to division by zero.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A simple calculator</title>
<script language="text/javascript">
function validate(b,op)
{
    var newval=b;           
    if(b=="0"&&op=="/")
           newval=prompt("Enter a non-zero value for B:",1);
    document.CalculatorForm.textbox2.value=newval;  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="CalculatorForm" method="get" action="http://localhost:8080/hello/CalculatorServlet" onsubmit="validate(this.textbox2.value,this.dropdown.options[this.dropdown.selectedIndex].value);">
A:<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="T1" /><br>
B:<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="T2" /><br>
Operation<br>
<select name="dropdown" id="dd">
<option value="+">Add</option>
<option value="-">Subtract</option>
<option value="*">Multiply</option>
<option value="/">Divide</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="compute"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Has it thrown any errors to firebug?

Comment: -1 What is the problem ? PLEASE, be more precise, add the bug, add the error or anything that can help us more than "it doesn't work, help"

Comment: What do you spect to happen? Is there a javascript validation error?, or your validation logic fails?

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to:

```
function validate()
{
    var b = document.getElementById('T2').value;
    var op = document.getElementById('dd')
    var opValue = op.options[op.selectedIndex].value; 
    if(b=='0' && op=='/')
         //do something  
    else
      // submit
}
```

Comment: I am comparing the values. Your code gets the selectedIndex and places in op.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I have changed the code ... can you check?

Comment: Doesn't work. I am stuck. Anyway thanks for your suggestion. Typo:should have been opValue=="/".